# Pandas Map on some rows only?

Tags: pandas

Is there a way to use pandas map on only some rows and ignore all others?

Example DF :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ProductID': ['Playstation','Playstation','Playstation','Sony Playstation','Sony Playstation','Sony Playstation'],
'date': [dt.date(2022,11,1),dt.date(2022,11,5),dt.date(2022,11,1),dt.date(2022,11,10),dt.date(2022,11,15),dt.date(2022,11,1)],
'customerID' : ['01','01','01','01','02','01'],
'brand': ['Cash','Cash','Game','Cash','Cash','Game'],
'gmv': [10,50,30,40,50,60]})
```

As you can see, I have similar products that, for some reason, are sometimes as "Playstation" and sometime as "Sony Playstation".

How can I do a pandas map to replace "Playstation" to "Sony Playstation"?
Take into that this is an example with only 2 brands. On my DF I have several brands, so make a dict of them is not viable (and I might need to change many brandes at once).

Can I apply map on a filtered df? I´ve tried apply map on partial DF:

```
Gift.loc[(Gift.brand == 'PlayStation')].brand.map({'PlayStation': 'Sony PlayStation'}, na_action='ignore')
```

If so, how to I move the new data to origim df?

Comment: Hi, what happens with `df["ProductID"] = df["ProductID"].replace({"Playstation": "Sony Playstation"})`?

Comment: I've used replace as solution for now. But in the case you sugeested, replacing Playstation for Sony Playstation get me some "Sony Playstation Playstation" lol